# Error Installing aws-sam-cli with homebrew on Mac: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to install `aws-sam-cli` with homebrew but I keep running into errors with pip.

Command: `brew install --build-from-source aws-sam-cli` (A suggestion from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2101))

Full log output:

> Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/aws/aws-sam-cli/tarball/v1.53.0
> Already downloaded: /Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/83481a8e9be3330f9960015919f25317b568fa8de7b6356eb075525e3e195f23--aws-aws-sam-cli-v1.53.0-0-gd2ded65.tar.gz
> ==> Installing aws-sam-cli from aws/tap
> ==> python3.8 -m venv --system-site-packages /Users/xxxx/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec
> ==> /Users/xxxx/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
> ==> /Users/xxxx/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/bin/pip install -v --ignore-installed /private/tmp/aws-sam-cli-20220810-6534-nwvmma/aws-aws-sam-cli-d2ded65
> Last 15 lines from /Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/Homebrew/aws-sam-cli/03.pip:
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> full command: /Users/xxxx/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.53.0/libexec/bin/python3.8 /private/tmp/pip-standalone-pip-npto4dyu/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/tmp/pip-build-env-3hf8bh7a/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel
> cwd: [inherit]
> Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

> × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)'))) - skipping

I don't have access to `sudo`, so I can't run administrative commands. I'm able to install sam with `pip install aws-sam-cli` though.

I've also tried some suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi), setting `~/.config` to

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.org pypi.io
```

Edit: Brew Configurations:

`brew config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.5.8
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: ff9c2500195cc357d4a06f99d462f8d8a5d37892
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: cbee80e4907b6d2f643cc7108d4197211ea28917
Core tap last commit: 72 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /Users/xxxx/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /Users/xxxx/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /Users/xxxx/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 13.1.6 build 1316
Git: 2.32.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.79.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.5-arm64
CLT: 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

`brew doctor`

```
Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew.
Some of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default
prefix (/opt/homebrew).
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving any issues you experience while you are running this
unsupported configuration.

Warning: /private/tmp is world-writable but does not have the sticky bit set.
To set it, run the following command:
  sudo chmod +t /private/tmp
```

And my Path has been reconfigured to: `/Users/xxxx/Library/Python/3.8/bin/:/Users/xxxx/homebrew/bin:/Users/Ufuoma.Apoki/.serverless/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Like I said previously, I don't have admin privileges so I can't install in `/opt` and I can't run `sudo chmod +t /private/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with installation aws-sam-cli and this finally helped me:

```
python3 -m pip install aws-sam-cli
```

Comment: This installs the package - but does not add to PATH?

Comment: For me I had to add "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin" to my path

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
brew tap aws/tap
brew install aws-sam-cli
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-mac.html).